# nested images (background) bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

hi guys i was trying to come up with the attached image, nested images using the grid in bootstrap. Image 3 should be over image 1 and 2[image]  any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what you are having issue with? Did you do anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) and [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) properties in CSS. This is neither related to bootstrap, nor related to *nesting* images.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it can help you to understand how you can position: Check the `codepen` [link](https://codepen.io/joaoskr/pen/YJxxbO)

Comment: is it responsive ?

Comment: Its a bit responsive, to make it responsive you must edit the height of div for each media size.